# Undefined variable role in php codigneter

Tags: php

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: role
>
> Filename: views/sample_list.php
>
> Line Number: 9

```
 <?php if($role[0]['sample']==1){?><a href="<?php echo site_url();?>/welcome/save_sample"><button class="btn btn-add  waves-effect waves-light" type="button">Add Sample</button></a><?php }?>
```

Comment: So what's your question? The message is pretty clear. You're using an undefined variable. It simply doesn't exist in that scope.

Comment: check from the controller u passed `$role` or not and  in view also chek with `isset($role[0]['sample'])`

Comment: update question with `$role` array details

Comment: @AbhishekSharma - Considering the error message saying that the variable `$role` is undefined, how would they then be able to show us details about it?

Comment: then check if variable is set or not as `if( isset($role[0]['sample']) && $role[0]['sample']==1)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

place checking with the condition

```
<?php if((!empty($role[0]['sample']))&&($role[0]['sample']==1)){?><a href="<?php echo site_url();?>/welcome/save_sample"><button class="btn btn-add  waves-effect waves-light" type="button">Add Sample</button></a><?php }?>
```